# insert object with foreign key with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, insert, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 objects: user and car.

I am trying to insert a car object with hibernate which has foreign key dependency of a user id.  A car has a single user and so I assigned a one to one relationship.

My car mapping looks like so (i removed the < because the xml wasn't showing up):

```
id name="id" type="int">
    <column name="carId" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
<property name="carName" type="string"></property>
<one-to-one name="user" class="User"></one-to-one>
```

My user mapping just has an id plus fields first name, etc.

My car object looks like so:

```
 private int id;
 private String carName;
 private User user;
```

My car table has a foreign key that is a userId.

When I attempt to insert I get a sql error: Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value

The sql that hibernate is doing is: 
      Hibernate: insert into car (carId, carName) values (?, ?)

As you can see the userId is missing and is a required field.

I need to insert a car object based on a userId to tie it to a user.  How can I accomplish this since the mapping I have is not accomplishing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the fact that a car is associated to one user doesn't necessarily make it a one-to-one. That would be true if a person can have only one car. It a person can have several cars, the association is a many-to-one.

Second, assuming thet the association is indeed a one-to-one, here's how [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-unidirectional-121) maps such an association:

> A unidirectional one-to-one association on a foreign key is almost identical. The only difference is the column unique constraint.

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="address" 
        column="addressId" 
        unique="true"
        not-null="true"/>
</class>
```